# Exception when using play framework 1.2.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: playframework-1.x

My instance of play v1.2.3 on Ubuntu was working fine till yesterday.  I am not entirely certain if I installed any new packages on Ubuntu in the meanwhile.  When I now try running play (run/start), I get the exception copied below.  I have tried cleaning the tmp directory but it did not help.  Any other thoughts (besides setting up play again) will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.vfs.VirtualFile.contentAsString(VirtualFile.java:180)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.getClassDefsForFile(ClassStateHashCreator.java:83)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.scan(ClassStateHashCreator.java:58)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.scan(ClassStateHashCreator.java:63)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.scan(ClassStateHashCreator.java:63)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.scan(ClassStateHashCreator.java:63)
    at play.classloading.hash.ClassStateHashCreator.computePathHash(ClassStateHashCreator.java:48)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.computePathHash(ApplicationClassloader.java:371)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.<init>(ApplicationClassloader.java:62)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:272)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at play.libs.IO.readContentAsString(IO.java:62)
    at play.libs.IO.readContentAsString(IO.java:49)
    at play.vfs.VirtualFile.contentAsString(VirtualFile.java:178)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1364)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1340)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1315)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:525)
    at play.libs.IO.readContentAsString(IO.java:60)
```

Comment: I was able to revert to an older version of my code and it worked fine.  I am trying to figure out whether reading any of the config files previously caused the issue - will update the post once done.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Java classes in my project somehow got corrupted.  I noticed it when I tried copying the whole directory to another location - the copy operation generated an error message specifying the corrupted file (which I'm sure one could have detected through other means as well).

Removing the corrupted file (& replacing with the same code) resulted in normal behavior.  Hope this helps others.